# $\phi:\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}_6$ where $\phi(1) =2$ prove $\ker\phi =3\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

$\phi:\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}_6$  where $\phi(1) =2$ prove $\ker\phi =3\mathbb{Z}$

I understand this one, I'm just having issues on how to write it

$\phi(1) =2 \implies \phi(1+1) = 4 \implies \phi(1+1+1) = 0$

or in other words if $3 |n, n \in \mathbb{Z}$ then $\phi(n) = 0$

$ker(\phi)$ is everything mapping to $0 \in \mathbb{Z}_6$

$3\mathbb{Z} = \langle3\rangle = \{n\,\,:\,\, n= 3m , m \in \mathbb{Z}\}$

It's not a hard problem. just stuck on how to show it in a "good" way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have shown is $3\Bbb Z\subseteq\ker\phi$. You also need to show if $n\in\ker\phi$ then $3|n$. Here's a way to do both at the same time.

Let $[n]$ be the congruence class of $n\pmod 6$.  Then $\phi(n)=[2n]$.

$$\begin{align}
[2n]=[0] & \iff 6|2n\\
& \iff 2n=6m,\text{ for some }m\in\Bbb Z\\
& \iff n=3m\\
& \iff 3|n.
\end{align}$$

Comment: Yes, right you are.